# Database backup using pg_dump

Tags: java, database, postgresql, docker

I want to get queries for backup of my dockerized psql database.
Is there any way to do this without installing pgAdmin on my pc (ubuntu)? Is it possible to do this from Intellij level? I was trying to use functions from IDE but nothing worked.

Comment: Why would you need pgAdmin if you want to use `pg_dump`?

Comment: a read that some people are using it, then what should i do, should I download pg_dump?

Comment: If you install PostgreSQL, that will automatically install `pg_dump`.